# How to show inline images in org-brain?

Tags: inline-image

I set

> (setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)

but opening a org file from within org-brain visualize I have to type twice

> C-c C-x C-v

To show up image.  Even If a set at the beginning of each of org document

```
#+STARTUP: inlineimages
```

mages

It wont show the image.  But if I open directly the org document (C-x C-f) then image is showed.

Is there any way to set org-brain to show images automatically ?

Comment: Make sure that you spell it correctly: `#+STARTUP: inlineimages`. I don't know anything about `org-brain`, but it seems to work properly in a basic Org file with current Org-mode (9.6) both with the in-file setting and the customization setting. I may be misremembering but I think I had run into this problem with an earlier version of Org mode, so it may be that if you upgrade, the problem will go away.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.  Updated to org 9.6 but nothing changed.  In org-mode it is fine but in org-brain-visualize mode not (need hit C-c C-x C-v to show inline images).

Comment: Ah OK, not sure what `org-brain` does to mess things up, but you probably should report it to them, since it works in plain Org mode.